# Why do we declare URL variable as private static String in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I know that for url we use String but why do we make it private static

Comment: Who says we declare it as `private static`? I never saw it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know anything about selenium but i know private and static.

A **private** member is only accessible within the same class as it is declared. So you cant access your url from another class or packages.

A **static** member is a member of a class that isn't associated with an instance of a class. Instead, the member belongs to the class itself. As a result, you can access the static member without first creating a class instance. So static variable are global variables they are created before class creation.

Hope you can figure out :)

Answer (score 1):

`String` is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), once an object is created you can't change its value. By declaring your URL as `private static` you declare, that you expect only a single URL `String` instance which will be shared between objects of your class (although you are not using `final` so you possibly want to change URL value).

This is not a requirement though and declaring constants as separate fields is usually done to improve code readability. Note, that compile-time `String` constants are [interned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) by the the Java compiler during compilation.